# How to get product name and product description from AssemblyInfo?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I need to get the product name and description from the AssemblyInfo.vb in ASP.NET. I know how to get the version number, but I couldn't find a way to get any other information.

```
Reflection.Assembly.Load("App_code").GetName().Version
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Assembly.Load("App_code").GetCustomAttributes(GetType(AssemblyProductAttribute), False).First().Product
```

Thanks to @dropoutcoder

Answer (score 1):

You have to look for attributes declared on the assembly level.

```
Dim asm As Assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly() // Change as needed
Dim product As String


If (asm.IsDefined(GetType(AssemblyProductAttribute))) Then
        product = asm.GetCustomAttributes(Of AssemblyProductAttribute).First().Product
End If
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: First of all, thanks for the response.  
Unfortunately, it did not work for me. I couldn't find "GetCustomAttribute". I did find "GetCustomAttributes" but it required two parameters and returns an array of objects.

Comment: Wait a moment. I'll run it in VS and change the answer.

Comment: I'm not sure where the `GetCustomAttribute` method used in the answer comes from but the `Assembly` class does have a `Shared` method of that name that has a number of overloads.

Comment: @jmcilhinney: I am living C# world. I didn't noticed it is VB.

Comment: @SA45CAL: Sorry for C# example. I've changed it to VB.NET.

Comment: I would think that you could collapse the `If` block using null propagation: `product = asm.GetCustomAttributes(Of AssemblyProductAttribute).FirstOrDefault()?.Product`.

Comment: @dropoutcoder That did not work either, here's what did:  

`Assembly.Load("App_code").GetCustomAttributes(GetType(AssemblyProductAttribute), False).First().Product`  

@jmcilhinney I got an error: "Visual Basic 12.0 does not support null conditional operations."